# Turn on/off HTML markup while coding?

Tags: html, text-editors

A frequent problem I'm having when editing web pages is that HTML jargon can get in the way, when I need to focus on just the content for making corrections. Once markup is added to a piece of text, img tags, hyperlinks, divs and all of their attributes can take multiple lines. Even with good indentation and spacing, simple semantic elements like em & strong can severely impair readability.

Here is what DOES NOT solve the problem for me:

1. Editing content separately in plain text, Markdown or rich text program. It is OK to write in a text editor during the initial stages of preparing content, but once a text document gets marked up with HTML, should you decide to make a change in the content, you have to then edit it in two or more places: at least once in the HTML & once in the original text file.
2. HTML expanders like Emmet. Text expanders help when adding elements, but they do nothing to improve readability once the elements are in place.

Quasi-solutions:

1. Pre-processors like HAML & Jade. Those can make a document more readable, but have their own peculiarities. Markdown, although great for readability has limited HTML capabilities before conversion.
2. WYSIWYG editors. In a traditional editor I could go into the Design mode and make changes to the rendered page directly without any HTML artifacts. This is great, but I have to constantly double check between code view & design view in order to monitor how changes are reflected in the code, which sort of defeats the whole purpose.

The Ideal solution

Ideally, an editor that turns on/off markup in code view or a meta-language that makes an HTML document Markdown-like readable would get the job done. In other words, does a tool/lightweight language that separates pure content from semantic structure exist?

Comment: This question is very close to a software recommendation request, unfortunately.  The only solution I can think of is to find a text editor that allows text hiding/concealing.  Vim has this feature, and I learned how to make it hide certain tags that appear more often in text content, but it's a bit of a kluge and doesn't hide all tags.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why a WYSIWYG doesn't work for you?  Why are you double-checking what HTML Was used?

Comment: @Heptite Isn't there a meta-language/pre-processor that might be more readable while not removing HTML essentials?

Comment: @ernie The reason is: there are times when you need to code, and times when you need to edit the base content. I need to be able to switch between bare content and markup to do this.

Comment: So, I'm still not sure what doesn't work about the WYSIWYG?  Are you saying that the code it writes is wrong?  You don't like it's formatting?  Unreadable?  WYSIWYG lets you flip back and forth, which is the requirement you've stated above . . . it's unclear to me what other constraints exist?  In fact, a WYSIWYG seems to match what what you're describing in your ideal solution - a content-only view and a code view?

Comment: @ernie Again, a WYSIWYG visually duplicates the content rather than show/hide details in the code itself. The design view is made to primarily show a rendered page. On top of that, edits in WYSIWYG are frequently imperfect & mess up good code unless I watch for it, which is unacceptable & extra work. The ideal tool I'm looking for has ONE code view, which allows to collapse/expand the markup when necessary.

Comment: All right, so you want code your way but you generally don't want to see it.  Your issue with the WYSIWYG is that it generates code differently than you write it.  I'm not sure you're going to find a tool that basically hides all the markup and restores it that's not a WYSIWYG . . . good luck.

Comment: I'm sorry, but as it stands your question just can't really be answered because it's both too broad and too narrow.  I'm inclined to vote to close it.

Comment: Looking for code writer with an ESP module combined with a DWIMNWIS logic system. It's the 64 billion dollar tech answer computer AI scientists have been looking for, for several decades. GLIYFI...

Answer (score 2):

For HTML editing I use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). This is a free, open-source, lightweight texteditor with syntax highlighting. It has all sorts of features inside to make any form of code readable. For example, commonly used tags are coloured differently than normal text, their parameters are differently coloured as well, and it can higlight the start and end of tags you're editing within.

For example:

[image: notepad++ html example]

Comment: code coloring doesn't cut it. I need to abstract the markup entirely ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "abstract the markup? I fail to understand what you seek.

Comment: They wants Word For Websites. If Dreamweaver doesn't do it then NSL.